# how to load images of css file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have problem to load images in coedigniter, with the help of `base_url()`, i succeed to load css but unfortunately images not.
Actualy images are called in css file(style.css), so to load style.css i changed in html like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

okay it is loading all style and css but the image are not loading which is used in styl.css
preview of css:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: url(images/img04.jpg) repeat left top;
}
```

so any idea any suggestion will be highly appreciate.
thank you

Comment: If you have as many typos in your code as you have in your question, I'd start fixing those... other than that, you need to change the image path to be relative from your css file (what you currently have means it will look for the image in /css/images/). What's your directory structure?

Comment: images/application/view

Comment: your application in under images folder..??

Comment: no no.................. i showed the path between images and view

Comment: That makes no sense...

Comment: if anyone asked to show us the folder structure ...we need to start it from root

Comment: i m on localhost....thats y i showed it like that

Comment: so then localhost/your_application_folder/

Comment: under that application,system,static,themes folders would be there,and you need to put images ,css folders under static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
body {
    background:url('../images/img04.jpg') repeat left top;
}
```

Comment: I assumed that your images folder in static

Comment: ya ...and try this also, but sir if we loaded the css then the images within css file should load automatic....is'nt???

Comment: ya.....................

Comment: Nope I think its not possible

Comment: And try background:url(../images/img04.jpg) repeat left top !important;

Comment: so what's the problem...

Comment: not loaded image yet.....

Comment: plz show me the folder struct first

Comment: I think it would be like "left top repeat" instead of "repeat left top"

Comment: images/application/view